# Not getting event arguments in IHTMLElement event handler

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, mshtml

I've added a callback to an IHTMLElement instance but when the IDispatch::Invoke is called for the event, there are never any arguments (i.e. the pDispParams->cArgs and pDispParams->cNamedArgs are always 0). For example, I add a callback for an onmouseup event. From what I can tell, a callback for this event is supposed to receive a MouseEvent object. Is that correct? If so, what do I need to do to ensure this happens?

This is using the MSHTML for IE 6 sp2 (or better) on Windows XP SP2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Events arguments for all DOM events including `onmouseup` are stored in the parent window's `event` property (`IHTMLWindow2::event`)

If you don't already have the parent window cached, `IHTMLElement` has a `document` property which returns an `IHTMLDocument` interface. From that you can query for `IHTMLDocument2` which has a `parentWindow` property. The `IHTMLWindow2` that is returned has the `event` property you're looking for. You should be able to query for the event interface from there.