# How can I attach a .NET delegate to an mshtml event?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, events, mshtml

I'm working on an extension (BHO) for Internet Explorer, and having trouble attaching a .NET delegate to the mshtml objects to catch DOM events.

I've tried using the events published by the IHTMLElementEvents2_Event, ... interfaces, and that works, but only if I specify the correct type for the DOM element whose events I want to catch.  I also need to specify in code the type of the element, and this technique doesn't allow for catching custom DOM events.

I've also tried using the [HtmlEventProxy class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/NetHtmlEventHandler.aspx), which attaches IDispatch objects to the DOM elements via the IHTMLElement2.attachEvent method, but that isn't working for me at all.  When I try to access the event object as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110015/not-getting-event-arguments-in-ihtmlelement-event-handler), I get a hang when accessing the DOM element's document property.

So how can I attach event handlers to DOM elements without needing to special case every kind of element and every kind of event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Foo
{
  public Foo(HtmlDocument doc) 
  {
    IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = (IHTMLDocument2)doc.DomDocument;
    doc2.onkeydown = this;
  }

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispId(0)]
  public void EventHandler()
  {
    IHTMLWindow2 win2 = (IHTMLWindow2)_doc.Window.DomWindow;
    IHTMLEventObj e = win2.@event;

    if (e.keyCode == (int)Keys.F5)
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```